# Ionic 3 + Protractor trigger swipe gesture ( e2e tests should run in Chrome browser or on device through Appium ?? )

Tags: ionic-framework, protractor, appium, gesture

[image]I am very new to writing E2E tests using protractor for Ionic apps that involve triggering gestures like Swipe on a div.

Following are my questions

1) How can we trigger a Swipe ( left or right ) gesture on a div so that it can be expanded or collapsed horizontally ??

2) Can such a protractor test execute on Chrome browser on a desktop computer or will need to be executed through Appium on actual device ??

3) Can you please provide me code snippets which will help me understand how to do it or how to proceed with it ?

I am not able to find any thing on the internet.

I have tried this post

[swipe and click a button protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209499/swipe-and-click-a-button-protractor?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But it's just not working for me & I am not getting any error or effect of it.

Comment: What is the error and what is the code that you've used.

Comment: @demouser123

please see my updated post above. All the help is welcome from your side please please.

Comment: @demouser123 I have also uploaded an image to give you an idea of what I am trying to test.

Comment: You need to update the post with the code you're testing. You've tried the linked answer, update your question with the applicable parts of your template html and protractor tests you have tried so we can help.

Comment: You can also try this answer [Swipe using flickElement]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60705604/8023150

Comment: You can also try this solution [swipe using flickElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60705604/8023150)